# Bash - Exit parent script from child script

Tags: bash

I have a Bash parent script that on unexpected input calls an error logging  child script that logs the error. I also want the execution to halt when the error occurs and the error script is called. But if I call `exit` from the error handling script it does not stop the parent script from executing. How may I go about stopping a parent script from a child?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try..

```
#normal flow
[[ $(check_error_condition) ]] && /some/error_reporter.sh || exit 1
```

so,

- when the error_reporter will exit with exit status > 0 the parent will terminate too
- if the error_reporter will exit with status = 0 the parent continues...

You don't want `stop the parent from a child` (*the parents usually don't like this behavior*) :), you instead want `tell to parent - need stop` and he will stop itself (if want) ;)

Comment: I believe your test lacks a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @bleistift2 corrected after 7 years... :) :) Thanx. :)

Comment: This is very confusingly worded... I would first describe that you have to do this in parent instead, and then describe the implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

In parent script:

```
trap "echo exitting because my child killed me.>&2;exit" SIGUSR1
```

In child script:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 `ps --pid $$ -oppid=`; exit
```

---

Other way was:

In child script:

```
kill -9 `ps --pid $$ -oppid=`; exit
```

But, it is not recommended, because the parent needs to have some information about getting killed & thus do some cleanup if required.

---

Another way:
Instead of calling the child script, `exec` it.

---

However, as pointed out in other answer, the cleanest way is to exit from parent, after the child returns.

Comment: It starts here look like in horror - the child kill the parent... :) :) (but yes, it IS a solution too) :) :)

Comment: ^^ Yups.... I once had a requirement like this: `command1 | (command 2; command3)` & command3 was supposed to kill command1 with SIGINT :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to terminate the parent from the child. Instead call `exit` in the parent after the child script returned.

```
if [ condition ]; then
  /path/to/child.sh
  exit 1
fi
```

or shorter

```
[ condition ] && { /path/to/child.sh; exit 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension to @anishsane comment because MacOS has little bit different `ps` syntax.

Finding parent process ID (ppid) in child script under Mac OS (Darwin):

`kill -SIGUSR1 $(ps $$ -o ppid=);exit`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, using
`set -e`
at the top of your script might be a good solution. This will automatically cause the script to exit if any commands (e.g., your error checking script) exit with a non-zero exit code (https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/)

Note that there are some common commands that have non zero exit codes under normal circumstance.