# Jump to the top parent shell from any arbitrary depth of subshell

Tags: bash

I created multiple subshells

```
$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501  2659  2657   0  8:22AM ttys000    0:00.15 -bash
  501  2776  2659   0  8:23AM ttys000    0:00.02 bash
  501  2778  2776   0  8:23AM ttys000    0:00.09 bash
  501  3314  2778   0  9:13AM ttys000    0:00.26 bash
  501  8884  3314   0  4:41PM ttys000    0:00.03 /bin/bash
  501  8891  8884   0  4:41PM ttys000    0:00.01 /bin/bash
  501  8899  8891   0  4:41PM ttys000    0:00.02 /bin/bash
  501   423   408   0  7:16AM ttys001    0:00.22 -bash
  501  8095   423   0  3:52PM ttys001    0:00.15 ssh root@www.****.com
  501  8307  8303   0  4:05PM ttys002    0:00.17 -bash
```

I'd like to jump back the most top one, but have to try exit one by one

```
$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501  2659  2657   0  8:22AM ttys000    0:00.17 -bash
  501   423   408   0  7:16AM ttys001    0:00.22 -bash
  501  8095   423   0  3:52PM ttys001    0:00.15 ssh root@***.com
  501  8307  8303   0  4:05PM ttys002    0:00.17 -bash
```

I checked there are 3 bashes left, so I continue,

```
$ exit
logout
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Sad, it's the most cases I encounter, How could I jump to the top from arbitrary depth of subshells?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - Exit parent script from child script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215196/bash-exit-parent-script-from-child-script)

Comment: Find the PID of the topmost shell that you want to leave, and `kill -9 that_pid`

Comment: I would advise against `kill -9`. Would be way better not to start so many subshell in the first place. Why do you even need them?

Comment: I don't think "top parent shell" is entirely well-defined anyway. Do you mean a login shell? (What about running under `tmux` or `screen`?)